# Can not pull in the "value" component of the Key\Value pair into the CSV result set

Tags: powershell, foreach-loop-container, pscustomobject

The program disables the feature "internet Explorer 11 after looping through a list of servers and exports the results to a csv file with Server Names and the "state" of the Internet explorer as columns as shown below but **value component** does not show up in the resulting csv file, specifically this value : $Status

ServerName                     State

genericNameServer             It is supposed to be either "disabledPending
or "Unknown", but it stays blank

```
#Filter the list of servers based on the input parameters (filtering in this location prevents having to loop through servers that are not being processed)
$FilteredServers = $AllServers | Where-Object { ($PSItem.OS -like "*$OperatingSystem*") -and ($PSItem.Type -eq $Type) -and ($PSItem.Citrix -eq $False)}

#Iterate through the list of servers
foreach ($Server in $FilteredServers)

    #if the server is 2012/2016
    elseif ((($OperatingSystem -eq '2012') -or ($OperatingSystem -eq '2016')))
    {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName ($Server.ServerName) -ScriptBlock { 
            #Disable IE
            dism /online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64 /NoRestart

            #Get the Interenet Exploere feature 
            $IEStatus = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64
          
           }

# evaluate if state property is disabledpending or not  and create a variable called Status  with a value of either 'disablepending' or 'status: unknown'
            if ($IEStatus.State -eq 'DisablePending') { $Status = 'DisablePending' }
            else { $Status = 'Unknown' }
                       
        }
    
        $CsvStatus += [PSCustomObject]@{
            ServerName  = $Server.ServerName
            State = ($Status)
        } 
    }
}
$CsvStatus | Export-Csv -Path c"\tem\effectedServer.csv
```

Comment: It would help if you could describe the purpose of your script. Also, to help clarify the problem, it is good to narrow down your code to a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: This would be a good time to start learning how to use a debugger, which allows you to run your program line by line (aka single-stepping), at the press of a button. For each line of code, examine the state of _all_ variables and verify if the their values meet your expectations. I can only recommend the debugger build into VSCode with the PowerShell extension. For PS 5.x, PowerShell ISE also works (but is somewhat outdated).

Comment: Maybe change State = ($IEStatus.State) to State = $($IEStatus.State).

Comment: Bill, thank you for your advise, I edited the post, I hope it makes more sense now.  Could you look at and see why the $Status stays blank in the CSV file

Comment: thank you for the Debugger advise, also $($IEStatus) does not work either ,